# Nginx changing access logformat in nginx.conf has no effect

Tags: nginx

I am trying to change the log format `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to:

```
http {
log_format  custom '3,$time_iso8601,$cookie_binuDid,,IPS,,0,$remote_addr,??,Unknown,N,N,$content_type,content,fetch,N'
                  '$status,Y,$upstream_response_time,$status,$upstream_response_time,$upstream_response_length,$upstream_response_length'
                  '"$upstream_http_cache-control",$request_uri,,,,,000000,0,Unknown'

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  custom;
```

Yet my access log prints:

```
220.233.181.158 - - [08/Dec/2019:14:26:08 +0000] "GET /static/js/5.32912c95.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://example-3.com/auth" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

I did `service nginx restart` after the change, with no effect.

I guess there is another configuration file that needs to be changed, but I couldn't figure. Can someone please help? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please add server block config

Comment: You appear to be missing a trailing `;` from the `log_format` statement.